# I installed Sass, but it is not properly displaying in project

Tags: html, css, sass

So I installed Sass for my project via the CLI `npm install -g sass` but the CSS that I entered is not displaying. So after creating my `style.scss` file and entering my code, I compiled it using `live sass compiler`. As a result, the `style.css` and `style.css.map` files appeared (like they should).  I then went into my html file and imported it.

Am I importing my CSS file correctly into my HTML file? If you see below, I thought this how it should be done. I am not using any framework for this particular project.

Not sure what to be looking out for when issues like this arise, so any leads are appreciated.

[image]

My HTML file
My SASS file
[image]

Comment: "Am I importing my CSS file correctly into my HTML file?" — Do you have some reason to think it isn't? Doesn't it work when you test it in a browser?

Comment: Without being able to see any issues you're having, the main question would revolve around if the relative path in the line `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` points to where the `style.css` is located in relation to the HTML file shown. In this case, the CSS file would need to be in the same folder location as the HTML file.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css"> try this?

Comment: I believe the VS Code sass compiler has not been updated in awhile and I know a number of people that have had issues with it, if that is what you are using. If you have Sass installed on your computer then you can find your project files in your command line and compile with the command `sass --watch scss:css`. You'll have to first create separate folders for `css` and `scss` for that exact command to work